# Can testrpc handle a synchronous sendRawTransaction call?

Tags: web3js, testrpc

I have the following:

```
function sendRaw(msg) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var txHash = config.web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(msg);
    if (!txHash) { reject('Could not submit raw transaction.'); }
    else { resolve(txHash); }
  })
}
```

I want the `txHash` regardless of whether or not the contract did/will throw. When I run this with testrpc, my call somehow catches the contract throw as an error from testrpc and doesn't return the tx hash as it should.

Is this a testrpc problem? If so, is there a way to configure testrpc to not do this?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here. You can pass a block time parameter to testrpc. 0.1s does the trick for me:

`testrpc -b 0.1`